# PHP substr not working on Safari IOS

Tags: javascript, php, ios, safari, substr

I have a javascript that collects latitude and longitude from a users mobile device and send to a PHP script via ajax. Since the variables have a long decimal point, I need them trimmed down so I can compare them to the set of points in my database for each location. Works fine on android using chrome and opera on IOS it doesn't trim the variables at all so it is always showing a negative to my if statement.

```
list($lat,$long) = 
explode(',',htmlentities(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET['latlng']))));
echo 'Latitude: '.$lat.' Longitude: '.$long.'<br />';
$_SESSION['clat'] = substr($lat,0,-5);
$_SESSION['clong'] = substr($long,0,-4);

echo 'Latitude: '.$_SESSION['clat'].' Longitude: '.$_SESSION['clong'].'<br 
/>';
if($_SESSION['lat'] == $_SESSION['clat'] && $_SESSION['long'] == 
$_SESSION['clong']) {
echo "You are here";
```

So $lat and $long are the raw values from the device and $_SESSION 'clat' and 'clong' are supposed to be trimmed so they can be compared to values in database ($_SESSION['lat'] and long)

$lat and $_SESSION['clat'] are the same when echod on IOS device. Is there a reason this doesn't work? Is there an alternative?

Comment: This is not PHP but probably your client script, I would suggest to change your question title to more accurate

Comment: How is 'substr' not a PHP command??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of decimal points to be set to a specific amount, use round. The following will round a number to 6 decimal points:

```
round($mynumber, 6);
```

If I use 1.234567890, I will get 1.234568 (Notice that it rounds the last digit.)

Alternately, you can compare decimal numbers properly. I don't know why it is so hard to teach programmers to do it correctly. Suppose I have two decimal/float/double numbers and I want to see if they are the same. I take the absolute difference and compare it to a degree of accuracy...

```
if(abs(a-b)<0.000001) // they are close enough to being the same
```

Can you do that in a query? Sure:

```
select * from sometable where abs(myfield-1.23456789)<0.00001
```

I suggest doing it correctly, but you can use round. I strongly advice not using substr to round off numbers.

Comment: Your second solution worked for me, I never thought to do it that way but it seems like a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, Thanks!